# Between Date Range in a QUERY Not Working

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a Date for Example a Departure Date of a Flight for 15/01/2014 and I want to create a query that remind me 30 days before departure.

I tried the following in the CRITERIA but none of them work

```
DateAdd("m",1,[DepartureDate])>=Date()

Between DateAdd("m",1,[DepartureDate]) And [DepartureDate]

IIF(DateAdd("m",1,[DepartureDate]) < Date(), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You posted this quite a while ago, so I presume you managed to solve it.  But if not, here is an answer for you.

There are two ways to do this.

### Option One

The easiest way is to enter this in the CRITERIA of your DepartureDate field:

`=Date()+30`

### Option Two

Alternatively, you could create a new column in your query that you filter on.  To do this in your query, enter this in the FIELD row for a new column:

`30DaysAway: IIf([DepartureDate]-30=Date(),"yes","no")`

This will give you a new column in the query titled "30DaysAway".  In that column it will say "yes" if the departure date is 30 days away from today, and "no" for all other dates.

Then in the CRITERIA for that query field, enter "yes".

Either of these options will filter the list of results and only show you entries with a departure date that is 30 days away.